# Using meteor-jade with blaze rc1 release, how can I get iron-router to work?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I am currently working with Meteor using the new meteor-jade templating plug-in which relies on the meteor release blaze-rc1. Currently I have the latest Meteor installed 0.7.2 so to run meteor with blaze rc1 I run the command 
    `sudo mrt --release blaze-rc1`

Everything was working fine until I decided to add iron-router by using `mrt add iron-router`

I got the error:

```
While building package `jade`:
packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:125: HTML is not defined (compiling tests/tests.jade)
  at _.extend.visitTag (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:125)
  at _.extend.visitNode (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:89)
  at _.extend.visitBlock (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:73)
  at _.extend.visitNode (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:83)
  at _.extend.visitBlock (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:73)
  at _.extend.compile (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:21)
  at sourceHandler (packages/compileJade/plugin/handler.js:11)


While building plugin `compileJade` in package `jade`:
error: no such package: 'html-tools'
error: no such package: 'spacebars-compiler'
```

And when I run `sudo mrt --release blaze-rc1`

The server crashes with `ReferenceError: Router is not defined`

Which means I cannot use the Router object and iron-router isnt working with blaze-rc1 release and jade template plugin.

What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iron router requires to be checked out from a specific branch in order to be able to work with blaze. Therefore you need to modify `smart.json` file and change the `iron-router` key to look like the following:

```
"iron-router": {
  "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git",
  "branch": "blaze-integration"
}
```

after this in your project directory, run:

```
$ mrt install
$ mrt update
```

Of course, this works only when you are running meteor from the blaze-rc1 release.

Beware, though, iron router is not released, neither is blaze. Therefore I suggest you check back at the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/meteor-talk) for problems and workarounds.

Comment: Hmm I just added iron-router from branch blaze-integration like you specified and it installed correctly this time but my app is still crashing when I try and start it because it says ReferenceError: Router is not defined. And I use Router.configure and Router.map in my file

Comment: Do I need to hard install blaze-rc1 or is it ok to run with mrt --release balze-rc1. If so how do I hard install the blaze-rc1 so I don't need to run mrt with a specific release and it defaults to blaze-rc1. I don't know if this will solve my issue.

Comment: update your .meteor/release file so that it contains blaze-rc1 and then `meteor update --release blaze-rc1`

Comment: hmm I am now running with blaze-rc1 by default and my server is still crashing. So strange, I installed iron-router like you said and am using blaze-rc1, it should work right? Why is it still saying ReferenceError: Router is not defined?

Comment: Ah it is working now! I had to run meteor add iron-router in addition to mrt update and the changes you specified to the smart.json file. Thanks so much!